# I have two dataset and need to comapre string from one data set columns with other dataset column in R

Tags: r

I have two dataset and need to comapre string from one data set columns with other dataset column in R:

Below are the details. Case can be ignore

Can any one help me on this please.

First Dataset:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>instancename</th><th>hostname</th><th>sid</th><th> </th></tr><tr><td>instance1</td><td>server1</td><td> </td><td>sid1</td></tr><tr><td>instance2</td><td>server2</td><td> </td><td>sid2</td></tr><tr><td>instance3</td><td>server3</td><td> </td><td>sid3</td></tr><tr><td>instance4</td><td>server4</td><td> </td><td>sid4</td></tr><tr><td>instance5</td><td>server5</td><td> </td><td>sid5</td></tr><tr><td>instance6</td><td>server6</td><td> </td><td>sid6</td></tr></tbody>
```

Second Dataset:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>short_description</th><th>description</th></tr><tr><td>Kindly activate Server1 information</td><td>Kindly activate all sid3 and there is issue with instance3</td></tr><tr><td>server2: issue on instance2</td><td>find a sloution for this issue</td></tr><tr><td>Please fix the issue</td><td>issue is on Sid6</td></tr><tr><td>can you please check instance5 on server5</td><td>Sid5. Please look into this issue asap.</td></tr><tr><td>sid1: performance issue</td><td>server1 and sid1. Performance issue</td></tr><tr><td>Can you please check the issue</td><td>Can you please check the issues</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

I need final dataset like below

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>short_description</th><th>description</th><th>Final_output</th></tr><tr><td>Kindly activate Server1 information</td><td>Kindly activate all sid3 and there is issue with instance3</td><td>Server1,sid3,instance3</td></tr><tr><td>server2: issue on instance2</td><td>find a sloution for this issue</td><td>server2,instance2</td></tr><tr><td>Please fix the issue</td><td>issue is on Sid6</td><td>Sid6</td></tr><tr><td>can you please check instance5 on server5</td><td>Sid5. Please look into this issue asap.</td><td>server5,Sid5</td></tr><tr><td>sid1: performance issue</td><td>server1 and sid1. Performance issue</td><td>sid1,server1</td></tr><tr><td>Can you please check the issue</td><td>Can you please check the issues</td><td>no matches found</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: It is not easy to read your datasets. Please check this post for help https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/5184851. Also your screen shot is missing

Comment: where is the second dataset?

Comment: `dput` your second dataset.

Comment: I am sorry, added second data set

Comment: Please add it in way so that it is easily reproducible.

Comment: I don't why it is taking it as text format. Somone has changed format for me First and final data set. Firewalls restricting to attach screen shots.

Comment: Does upper case or lower case matter? Should "server1" and "Server1" be matched?

Comment: No matter on case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you provided data in html format, i will have to read it into r to be a table:

```
b ="<table><tbody><tr><th>short_description</th><th>description</th></tr><tr><td>Kindly activate Server1 information</td><td>Kindly activate all sid3 and there is issue with instance3</td></tr><tr><td>server2: issue on instance2</td><td>find a sloution for this issue</td></tr><tr><td>Please fix the issue</td><td>issue is on Sid6</td></tr><tr><td>can you please check instance5 on server5</td><td>Sid5. Please look into this issue asap.</td></tr><tr><td>sid1: performance issue</td><td>server1 and sid1. Performance issue</td></tr><tr><td>Can you please check the issue</td><td>Can you please check the issues</td></tr></tbody></table>"


dat2= xml2::as_xml_document(paste0("<body>",b,"</body>"))%>%
  rvest::html_table()%>%
  {.[[1]]}


serv_instance = gsub("(?|.*?((?i)server\\d+|instance\\d+|sid\\d+)|.+)","\\1",do.call(paste,dat2),perl=T)

final_output = replace(gsub("(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Za-z])",", ",serv_instance,perl=T),!nchar(serv_instance),"No match found")

cbind(dat2,final_output)

                          short_description                                                description             final_output
1       Kindly activate Server1 information Kindly activate all sid3 and there is issue with instance3 Server1, sid3, instance3
2               server2: issue on instance2                             find a sloution for this issue       server2, instance2
3                      Please fix the issue                                           issue is on Sid6                     Sid6
4 can you please check instance5 on server5                    Sid5. Please look into this issue asap. instance5, server5, Sid5
5                   sid1: performance issue                        server1 and sid1. Performance issue      sid1, server1, sid1
6            Can you please check the issue                            Can you please check the issues           No match found
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. I just edited my exact requirement, can you please help me?

Comment: @user3061575 are you scrapping a website? you should use `rvest` for that